# dynamic router in express

Tags: node.js, express

I have several types of projects, each project handles a different code.
I want to make a route handler for every project.

For example

- `router.use('/projects/dog_name', dog)`
- `router.use('/projects/cat_name', cat)`

The project name is dynamic and comes from retrieving data from the database and is updated from time to time.

What can I do?

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you are asking, but you can use route parameters as describe in the routing docs: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters. Something like `router.use('/projects/:project_name', handler)`. Inside the handler, you would read `req.params.project_name` to get the value dynamically.

Comment: Only according to the parameter can I know what handler

Comment: Sure, but that's on you. You would use a `switch` statement, or load the handler dynamically from the file system, or use a single unified handler, or any number of techniques... that's for you to decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's going to be code that decides how to treat the router, then you probably want one generic route that can then use code logic to distribute the handling of the route dynamically based on some sort of dynamic lookup:

```
  let dynamicRoutes = new Map([["golden", dog], ["persian", cat]]);

  router.use("/projects/:name", (req, res, next) => {
      let target = dynamicRoutes.get(req.params.name);
      if (target) {
           target(req, res, next);
      } else {
           next();
      }
  });
```

Then, you can add/remove items from the `dynamicRoutes` data structure to add/remove new dynamic routes at any time.  If you have logic involving a database lookup, you can use that instead of the `map.get()`.  Or, maybe for performance reasons, you don't query the database on every route hit, but rather query the database when something changes and update the `dynamicRoutes` data structure (like a cache) whenever you know something has changed in the database.